# Using git behind a proxy in python scripts

Tags: python, linux, git, proxy, yocto

I work with a proxy which doesn't like git. In most of the cases, I can use `export http_proxy` and `git config --global url."http://".insteadOf git://`.

But when I use Yocto's python script, this workaround doesn't work anymore. I'm systematically stopped at `Getting branches from remote repo git://git.yoctoproject.org/linux-yocto-3.14.git...`. I suspect these lines to be responsible :

```
gitcmd = "git ls-remote %s *heads* 2>&1" % (giturl)
tmp = subprocess.Popen(gitcmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

I think that after these lines, others will try to connect to git url. The script I use (`yocto-bsp`) calls others scripts, which call scripts, so it's difficult to say.
I have tried to add `os.system(git config --global url."http://".insteadOf git://)` just before, but it does peanuts.

Of course, I could try and modify all the url manually (or with a parsing script) to replace `git://` by `http://` manually, but this solution is... hideous. I'd like the modification(s) to be as small as possible and reproductible easily. But most of all, I'd like a working script.

EDIT : according to [this page](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/linux-yocto-3.14/), the git url is `git://git.yoctoproject.org/linux-yocto-3.14` but the correspondant http url is `http://git.yoctoproject.org/git/linux-yocto-3.14`, so I can't just parse to replace `git://` by `http://`. Definitely not cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, rewriting the git url does indeed work, also when using YP.

However, you're rewriting scheme doesn't work that well... You're just replacing the git:// part or the url with http://, but if you look at e.g. [linux-yocto-3.14](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/linux-yocto-3.14/), you'll see that this repo is available through the following two URL's:

```
git://git.yoctoproject.org/linux-yocto-3.14
http://git.yoctoproject.org/git/linux-yocto-3.14
```

That is you need to rewrite `git://git.yoctoproject.org` to `http://git.yoctoproject.org/git`. Thus, you'll need to do this instead:

```
git config --global url."http://git.yoctoproject.org/git".insteadOf git://git.yoctoproject.org
```

Which means that you'll have to repeat this exercise for all repositories that are accessed through the git protocol.